# awk + how to print each sec string (IP) after the first hostname

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, perl

how to print the following (output from API ) so IP address will be after the hostname

```
kafka02.ur.com
102.16.235.69
master01.ur.com
102.16.235.61
master02.ur.com
102.16.235.62
```

example

```
kafka02.ur.com     102.16.235.69
master01.ur.com    102.16.235.61
master02.ur.com    102.16.235.62
```

Comment: you can do it without awk. use: cat file | paste - -

Comment: see this topic: https://serverfault.com/questions/375096/bash-sed-awk-etc-remove-every-other-newline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -e 'N;s/\n/\t/' in.txt
```

joining each two lines together with single tab between

Answer (score 1):

```
$ paste - - <file
kafka02.ur.com  102.16.235.69
master01.ur.com 102.16.235.61
master02.ur.com 102.16.235.62
```

The `paste` command, when used with `- -` will read from standard input and distribute the incoming lines (from `file`) across two columns of output.

The delimiter will be a tab character, but this may be changed with the `-d` option.

With `awk` (as requested):

```
$ awk '{ printf("%s\t", $0) } { getline } { print }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{getline x; printf("%s\t%s\n", $0, x)}' file.txt
```

- `getline x` gets the next record and save as variable `x`
- `printf("%s %s\n", $0, x)` prints the records in desired format

---

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
kafka02.ur.com
102.16.235.69
master01.ur.com
102.16.235.61
master02.ur.com
102.16.235.62

% awk '{getline x; printf("%s\t%s\n", $0, x)}' file.txt
kafka02.ur.com  102.16.235.69
master01.ur.com 102.16.235.61
master02.ur.com 102.16.235.62
```